# SLES find what repo provides a package

Tags: repository, sles, zypper

I need to find out what repo 'git-core' comes from.

```
$ zypper search git-core
Refreshing service 'nu_novell_com'.
Removing repository 'SLE11-WebYaST-SP1-Pool' [done]
Removing repository 'SLE11-WebYaST-SP1-Updates' [done]
Adding repository 'SLES11-SP2-Updates' [done]
Adding repository 'SLE11-WebYaST-SP2-Pool' [done]
Adding repository 'SLES11-SP2-Extension-Store' [done]
Adding repository 'SLES11-SP2-Core' [done]
Adding repository 'SLE11-WebYaST-SP2-Updates' [done]
Adding repository 'SLE11-SP2-Debuginfo-Core' [done]
Adding repository 'SLE11-SP2-Debuginfo-Updates' [done]
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-SP2-Core' metadata [done]
Building repository 'SLES11-SP2-Core' cache [done]
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-SP2-Extension-Store' metadata [done]
Building repository 'SLES11-SP2-Extension-Store' cache [done]
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-SP2-Updates' metadata [done]
Building repository 'SLES11-SP2-Updates' cache [done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name     | Summary        | Type
--+----------+----------------+--------
i | git-core | Core git tools | package
```

Searching the man pages for zypper, it seems like 'what-provides' would provide this information. It just says "System Packages".

```
$zypper what-provides git-core
Refreshing service 'nu_novell_com'.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
S | Name     | Type    | Version        | Arch   | Repository
--+----------+---------+----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------
v | git-core | package | 2.0.0-201.1    | x86_64 | Software configuration management (SLE_11_SP2)
v | git-core | package | 1.6.0.2-7.31.2 | x86_64 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Software-Development-Kit-11-SP2 11.2.2-1.66
v | git-core | package | 2.0.0-201.1    | i586   | Software configuration management (SLE_11_SP2)
i | git-core | package | 1.8.4-165.1    | x86_64 | (System Packages)
```

These are the repos that exist.

```
ls /etc/zypp/repos.d/
nu_novell_com:SLE11-SP2-Debuginfo-Core.repo     nu_novell_com:SLES11-SP1-Pool.repo
nu_novell_com:SLE11-SP2-Debuginfo-Updates.repo  nu_novell_com:SLES11-SP1-Updates.repo
nu_novell_com:SLE11-WebYaST-SP2-Pool.repo       nu_novell_com:SLES11-SP2-Core.repo
nu_novell_com:SLE11-SP1-Debuginfo-Pool.repo     nu_novell_com:SLE11-WebYaST-SP2-Updates.repo    nu_novell_com:SLES11-SP2-Extension-Store.repo
nu_novell_com:SLE11-SP1-Debuginfo-Updates.repo  nu_novell_com:SLES11-Extras.repo                nu_novell_com:SLES11-SP2-Updates.repo
```

On CentOS I would run a `repoquery` or `yum info`. 
How can I tell which repo git 1.8.4 comes from on sles?

**Update**

I fixed this by using a SLES 11 SP2 image instead of SLES 11 SP1. Leaving question open if someone can still answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

simple `zypper info package`

for listing repos `zypper lr`

`@System` means package is installed but not available in any repo

LANG=C zypper info perl-BSXML
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

```
Information for package perl-BSXML:
-----------------------------------
Repository     : @System                                      
Name           : perl-BSXML                                   
Version        : 0.0-3.9                                      
Arch           : x86_64                                       
Vendor         : obs://build.opensuse.org/devel:languages:perl
Installed Size : 18.3 KiB                                     
Installed      : Yes                                          
Status         : up-to-date                                   
Summary        : XML templates for the BuildService           
Description    :                                              
    XML templates for the BuildService. See XML/Structured.
```

so Repository is @System and Vendor links to obs project from which package come

Answer (score 0):

I have SLES **11.4**, from that SLES SDK 11.4 it has git version 1.7.12.4-0.18.6.1.

The SDK for SLES 12.3 has git 2.12.3-26.1.

the **git-core** package is found under the software development kit part of SLES.  Look to download `SLE-11-SP4-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso` or whatever the correct version corresponds to your operating system version.

once SLES is registered for updates/patches, you can also find git under `SLE11-SDK-SP4-Pool` and `SLE11-SDK-SP4-Updates`.  *{should be SP2 in your case since you said you have SLES 11 sp2}*

if you need a specific git version, you would likely need to download the git source from `https://git-scm.com/downloads` look under the `older releases` and you can get git-1.8.4.1.tar.gz through git-1.8.4.5.tar.gz

** just notice the repo list you posted, has no SDK.  I am guessing your system was created and when it was registered there was no original SLES 11.2 SDK used... normally you have two repo's listed the SLES 11.x install dvd or iso, and the `SLES 11.x SDK` dvd or iso.  If you miss having the SDK present prior to registering the system to get the repositories, it does not (or did not back in 11sp2 days) automatically give you the SDK repository.